# Continuity function

Tags: functions, continuity

Let f be a continuous real function such that $f(11)=10$ and for all $x$, $f(x)f(f(x))=1$, then what is the value of $f(9)$.
I got $$f(10)=\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: This function probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @G-man - As per BerndH's post, $f(x) = 1/x, x \in [1/10, 10]$. Outside of this interval, it is sufficient that $f(11) = 10$, and the codomain of $f$ remains $[1/10,10]$, both of which are easily accomplished continuously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When $x = 11$, $f(11)f(f(11)) = 10f(10) = 1$, so that $f(10) = \frac1{10}$.

Now when $x = 10$, $f(10)f(f(10)) = \frac1{10}f(\frac1{10}) = 1$, so that $f(\frac1{10}) = 10$.

By intermediate value theorem, there is some $c$ in the interval $(10,11)$ so that $f(c) = 9$. Apply the given formula with $x = c$.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to andy walker's answer (sorry, I can't comment yet): If you fix $a=f(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then it is clear that the relation $af(a)=1$ holds, i.e. $f(a)=1/a$ for all $a$ in the codomain of $f$, that is $f(\mathbb{R})$.

So the argument can easily be extended to $f(x) = 1/x \ \forall x\in [1/10,10]$ in the first place.